# While using same spinner in all the activities

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using the same spinner to all the activities in my app. Let's say, items in spinner are English, Finnish, Polish, blah.. When I select Finnish in one activity, the dropdown of spinner gets close and Finnish can be seen on the spinner. But when I go to the next activity it does not show the Finnish anymore, instead, it shows English (item) at the top. Is there any method to make appear the item on the spinner that has been selected to all the activities. Or, should not change unless it has not been changed.
In BaseActivity;

```
int currentLanguage = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(currentLanguage);

Log.i("SET POSITION", Integer.toString(currentLanguage));
```

In other activity to save the state of item position;

```
int position = SharedMemory.getInstance().getCurrentPosition();
    Base_Activity.spinner.setSelection(position);
    Log.i("GET POSITION", Integer.toString(position));
```

I managed to set the selected language to set it in SharedMemory which is Singleton class. 
But how can I still get the same currentLanguage in all the activities. I am not able to get it when I change the activity. 
Note: this spinner is in action bar in Base_Activity class where all the other activities are extended this class.
Thank you.

Comment: try storing the selection in the sharedpreferences, and when you access the other activity in the onResume get the value from shared preferences and set the spinner position accordingly.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille  I am using Singleton class. Is it different than sharedpreferences. I do not prefer to change it not at the end of my project.

Comment: SharedMemory.getInstance().getCurrentLanguage(); you mean to say that this doesnt return the proper value ? have you tried calling it in the other activities in the first place?

Comment: setCurrentLanguage shud be static for u to get the lately updated value

Comment: In BaseActivity I set selected item of spinner as a currentLanguage and store in Singleton class. When I open app, it shows Main Activity, right? When I select there one item what will it be then? It should set or get CurrentLanguage. Because of Base Activity, spinner can be reachable from all the activities of my app

Comment: And it gives nullPointer exception when I use this code in Activity class(screens).
System.out.println(SharedMemory.getInstance().getCurrentLanguage());

Comment: by default the value will be set to the first item selected in the mainActivity, even if you donot select it, it is a natural behaviour of the spinner to call its onItemSelected function. Put logs, in your set and get methods, to see whats going wrong where,and in the set method, you should set the local variable to the variable you pass in the set method

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille some code hints plzz..I do not get you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve my problem. Before I was trying to do stuffs inside     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() method, which was really wrong. 
In my BaseActivity;

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();

    //creating the position of the language in spinner from arraylist 
    int currentLanguage = Arrays.asList(language_codes).indexOf(
            conf.locale.getLanguage());

    spinner.setSelection(currentLanguage);
```

This allows me the selected item of spinner remain on the top always when I even change the activities. Hope this might help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because the spinner in the other activity is different from the one in the first activity.

You will have to pass the current selection of the spinner as argument to the second activity and set the other spinners selection to that position.

In BaseActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("pos", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    startActivity(intent);
```

In second Activity:

```
    spinner.setSelection(getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0));
```

Comment: The spinner is in action bar which is in BaseActivity class.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Because I do not want to start activity on item click. I am changing the language. I am trying to access to change the language from any activity.

Comment: This need not be done on item click. where ever or whenever you are going to start the activity, just pass the current spinner's selection as in the code above.

Comment: I understand what u meant. But as I told you the spinner is in action bar in BaseActivity class. So all the other activities are extended with this class. Here I do not need to intent. When item is selected it refreshes the current activity with selected language.

Comment: okay. I hope I'm getting you now. Since one cannot predict when an activity is destroyed, its better not to be dependent on the spinner object in the parent activity. One suggestion is to save the spinner position say, in shared preferences, so that it it will always be available to other activities.

Comment: @Deepal Senapati . Exactly! I was expecting that answer. And I am trying to do do but failing all the time. If you could take a look at my starting code:
final String currentLanguage = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentLanguage(currentLanguage);
Here if I set the selected Item as a current language, how can I receive it in activities. :)

Comment: Could you help me how can I get the selected item to put on the top in another activity?

Comment: try using shared preferences. in BaseActivity: getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    .putInt("pos", position).commit();       In other activity:getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("pos", 0); Can pass string also if you want.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you take a look and guide me. I still cannot make it.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton class should probably look like this:

```
public class SharedMemory {
    public static SharedMemory sharedMem = new SharedMemory();
    private String valueSelected; // or position here

    public SharedMemory getInstance() {
        return sharedMem;
    }

    public String getCurrentLanguage() {
        Log.i("tag","valueSelected: " + valueSelected);
        return valueSelected;
    }

    public void setCurrentLanguage(String currLang) {
        valueSelected = currLang;
        Log.i("tag","valueSelected: " + valueSelected);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
onItemSelectedListener(...) {
    if(ShareMemory.getInstance().getCurrentLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
          // then set the value to 0
    }else {
       // set the value still but then set the gui also
    }
}
```

// in the onResume or onCreate method
write the following:

```
spinner.setSelection(ShareMemory.getInstance().getCurrentLanguage());
```

Using Log print the values in the singleTon class, and also the onItemSelected listener of the spinner.

Comment: It set right value[valueSelected: English or sthng]. But how to get it now on other activities?. When I use SharedMemory.getinstance.getCurrentLanguage(), it gives right values but not in the spinner. In spinner, I could not reference the valueSelected.

Comment: store the position of the item selected, when the new activity starts, using the get method of the singleton, u will get the position, in the onResume or the onCreate method of the activity, set the position of the spinner as, spinner.setSelection(value that you get);

Comment: "value that you get" should be an integer hence the position, so store the position of the item selected.

Comment: I am seeting and getting right value but when I go to next activity it is still forcing to set the item at position to the top. :(

Comment: When the activity gets created and when the spinner is set you will have to set the position of the spinner inside the OnItemSelected listener, check if the value is differnt than 2, if yes, set it to that value. check the edit for a clear idea

Comment: Could you check my edited question code part. And please guide me from there. I am about to cry now :(

Comment: When I go to the next activity, it again compile this; SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(currentLanguage);
You know why right? If I could stop to compile this code when I go to another activity. :(

Comment: try commenting that line and see what happens.

Comment: If I comment that, I cannot save the selected item position to sharedMemory. And then I cannot get to the another activity.Then in another activity I will get the position 0 (item at the top) Any logics, that the position is set to Shared Memory in some condition?

Comment: frankly, even if you have the spinner in the base activity, and all your activities extend it, the spinner would be recreated all the time, else the instance would have been maintained :).try setting it in the onItemSelected listener of the spinner like in this edit, inside the if

Comment: Is that equalsIgnoreCase("0") is the position of item in spinner?

Comment: since its an int you are using, simply compare them as the way integers are compared

Comment: int currentPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String position = Integer.toString(currentPosition);
    
if(position.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
     SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(0);
 Log.i("GET POSITION", Integer.toString(currentPosition));
 }else{     SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentPosition(currentPosition );}
Still not working :(